# Excel 2007 - Default parameter - Link update False - Open

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

I was wondering if it was possible to deactivate the update links in Excel 2007 by default.

The same way it can be done in vba when you are opening a file (workbooks.open path... updatelinks:= False)

Ok you change the parameters to always ask you if you want to update the links, but the problem is that I have a file where I can't find the cell with the links that point to a unknow location. So it take a while to open the file.

I have created a macro to open the file without updating links but I would like to have it standard in Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Excel user options there are some update link options. This screenshot is from Excel 2013 but the same options exist in 2007 just a different layout.

- Update links to other documents (WorkBook).
- Ask to update automatic links (General).

Note: One setting is for the current workbook and the other is a general XL option.

I'm thinking open a blank workbook and change the general setting. Then open your heavy-linked XL file and you should be asked if you want to update the links or not.

[image]